# Current status of US06/078,118

Tags: status

What is the current legal status of US patent application number 06/078,118? on Google patent it is "expired", while on Public Pair it is "patented case".

Comment: Please add a link to the document. The number format you list is not consistent with an application.

Answer (score 1):

US application 06/078,118, was granted as [US4378187A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4378187A/en?oq=06%2F078%2C118) on 01-26-1983. Since this is before 1995, the term of the patent would be 17 years from the grant date which results in an expiration date of 01-26-2000. As such, the patent has expired. I don't know of any provision that allows a patent to extend beyond its expiration date, especially one which should have expired so long ago.

I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal opinion.